# catch when someone completes the like action on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm looking for a way to fire a JS action when a visitor 'does' with the facebook 'like' button. There is `Event.subscribe('edge.create'..`, but it fires right after a visitor clicks the like button, giving them no chance to write a comment and 'share' on their profile.

I need an event which will be fired when someone closes the like box by using the 'close' button, or by sharing the page with a comment using the related button, so I can redirect them to the appropriate page when they're done.

Using a timeout is not possible cause they can write a comment in a few minutes, or just close the box instantly.

Comment: If you think this is a bug, file it at the [bug tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) - if you're asking a specific question about how to handle the callback, you should probably include a code sample and explain how you're tried to work around the issue

Comment: thanks Igy. I'm asking for a method to catch when a user closes the like box, by sharing or directly closing.

Comment: Well it's more of a bad implementation or unimplemented feature, so no. I modified the SDK so I got an event when the user does with the like box.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume any event not listed on Facebook's [`FB.Event.subscribe()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) page would be hard to accomplish because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Try to think about the problem from a user-experience perspective; the average user would expect that pressing the Like button would 'like' that page on Facebook, as that is the result we have all become familiar with.

If they were to be redirected, the result is not only completely unexpected, but you are also preventing them from unliking the page (if, for example, it was accidental). In this case, if you are using the Like button as some kind of Fan-gate, I suggest you show a 'continue' or 'next' button instead, so the user understands that they can progress (without introducing unexpected actions).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The redirected address is the same or a similar page, just to show the right state. Eg. stop showing Facebook's own 'like' button in the top, display the 'unlike' button, and stop asking the visitor to like the page. Or else Facebook's own like button in the top won't change its state.